# Making Items Non-Clickable

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have the follwing code:

```
<Pivot Grid.Row="1" x:Uid="Pivot" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
    <!--Pivot item draw-->
    <PivotItem x:Uid="PivotDraw" Margin="10,0,0,10" Header="drawx" DataContext="{Binding Draw}" d:DataContext="{Binding Draws[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:DataSource}}" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
        <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rounds}" IsRightTapEnabled="True" ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}">
                            <Run Text="Round "/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding RoundNumber}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Formations}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 5, 0" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Shorthand}"  Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </PivotItem>
```

At the moment I have data showing on that pivot page in the following format:

```
Round 1
A B C D E

Round 2 
F G H J K
```

I am struggling to make the individual formations (the letters), non-selectable.

At the moment I can press on any individual letter and it gives me the press animation on just that letter, I want to disable that.

I can also press on 'Round X' heading and I get the press animation for the whole item (round heading plus all formations), which I want to keep and add a method to.

I have tried adding `IsItemClickEnabled` to various places but haven't managed to change the current functionality as described above.

Comment: The best would be here to define a custom style for ListViewItem, there you would have to remove some code from VisualStateManager. But if you don't want to have an ability to select/touch those letters, I think you can try to set in second ListView in ItemContainerStyle, under the Marign: `<Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>`.

Comment: Are you following me? :) Works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be here to define a custom style for *ListViewItem*, there you would have to remove some code from *VisualStateManager*.

But if you don't want to have an ability to select/touch those letters, I think you can try to make some modifications in second *ListView.ItemContainerStyle*, - set `IsHitTestVisible` to *false*:

```
// .. code ...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Formations}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
              <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 5, 0" />
              <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
// rest of the code
```